# Rust integration testing, get thread/worker id?

Tags: rust

When testing with database it's sometimes useful to reset/seed database for specific test.

Rust runs test in parallel as far as I know and I would like each test/thread to use a separate database so that they would not conflict (one test reseting data for another running test).

In node testing frameworks we have environment variables like `VITEST_WORKER_ID` or [`JEST_WORKER_ID`](https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables) which can be used for example to run tests against different databases `test_db_1`, `test_db_2`.

Is there something like this in rust? Or some way to achieve this?

Comment: Would this help [std::thread::Thread::id](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.id) ?

Comment: @harmic but how does this work? Per test function or per file like in node and is it reliable ?

Comment: That would just give you the thread/worker ID as per your title, which sounds similar to the node variables you have mentioned. There could be more tests than threads though, so you cannot be sure that each test will get a unique thread ID.

Comment: @harmic but is it possible for 2 running tests to have same `thread ID`? It's fine for me if `thread ID` is reused later

Comment: No, each running test should have a separate thread id